# Magento 2 Redis Session Storage Database Table

Tags: magento2, redis, table

I have added Redis Session Storage to my Magento 2.1 site and am assuming it is working correctly because keys are in the database. I have looked at the table "session" in phpMyAdmin and noticed that it is still being filled with data even if I delete all entries. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure but are you seeing anything written to `var/session`?

Comment: I don't have a var/session folder

Comment: by default, session data is written to the file system so that is a good sign

Comment: On Magento 2.1 session data is written to the database by default